# PyQt access item from another class

Tags: python, pyqt

Im using PyQt and I need to access a list item from another class method, how do I do this?

I want to use the self.list_item in the item_click(self, item) method and use it in another class method.

```
Class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.LoadList()
        self.show()

    def LoadList(self):
        self.ui = Ui_List()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.item_click)
        self.ui.pushButton_Edit.clicked.connect(self.edit_project_btn)

    def item_click(self, item):
        self.list_item = str(item.text())
        self.ui.pushButton_Edit.setEnabled(True)

    def edit_project_btn(self):
        self.dialog = ProjectEdit()
        self.dialog.show()

class ProjectEdit(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ProjectEdit, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Edit()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton_ok.clicked.connect(self.close)
        ### access self.list_item here ####
```

Comment: Where do you initialize ProjectEdit?

Comment: I removed some code, but updated it to show that now

Comment: Why do you want to access list_item in the constructor of ProjectEdit?

Comment: you can pass the instance of the class to acces it, but the way to do this is raise a signal to update the value in the ProjectEdit class

Comment: @eyllanesc because I'm using it in a new dialog window

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should declare `list_item` and `dialog` in your `__init__` method:

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.list_item = None
        self.dialog = None
        self.LoadList()
        self.show()
```

Then you can just pass the parameter to your class constructor

```
def edit_project_btn(self):
    self.dialog = ProjectEdit(self.list_item)
    self.dialog.show()   

class ProjectEdit(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, list_item):
        super(ProjectEdit, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Edit()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton_ok.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.list_item = list_item
```